# How to publish message to selected specific nearby device with Google Nearby message API?

Tags: android, google-nearby

//Below for subscribe with nearby device

```
Nearby.Messages
      .subscribe(googleApiClient, messageListener, options)
      .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
          @Override
          public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
          }
      });
```

Below for publish message to Nearby Devices

```
Nearby.Messages
      .publish(googleApiClient, mPubMessage, options)
      .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
            }
      });
```

Comment: What's the actual problem you're having with this though? 
It's not clear from your question.

Comment: using above code we can publish a message to all nearby devices but i want to send message to specific devices not all devices for example there are 3 devices are connected with each other A,B,C. normally if A publish a message then B and C can receive that message but i want if A send the message then only B can recieve that message not C.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use Messages - they are a publish/discover pattern and you cannot select specific devices

You want Nearby Connections - https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/package-summary

This pattern is more for one-one connection